# Whenever I run my project in IntelliJ it works a fine, however whenever I attempt to run it as a jar it throws an exception

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a project which works fine within IntelliJ, however after building a jar from it i am getting the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.clearMetadataCache()V
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:183)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
```

I'm at a loss as to why it works fine in IntelliJ but not running the Jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help:

[NoSuchMethodError on compiling Spring Application with FileSystemXmlApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716832/nosuchmethoderror-on-compiling-spring-application-with-filesystemxmlapplicationc)

-- Answer from link --

You have incompatible jar files in your classpath. Check the Version of `spring-context-support` and `spring-beans`
The missing method was introduced in spring 4.2:

> void clearMetadataCache()
>
> Clear the merged bean definition cache, removing entries for beans
>   which are not considered eligible for full metadata caching yet. 
>   Typically triggered after changes to the original bean definitions,
>   e.g. after applying a BeanFactoryPostProcessor. Note that metadata for
>   beans which have already been created at this point will be kept
>   around.
>
> Since:4.2
>
> See Also:getBeanDefinition(java.lang.String),
>   ConfigurableBeanFactory.getMergedBeanDefinition(java.lang.String)

Check if Version of `spring-context-support` is the same then `spring-beans`